# Using Dropbox as storage in python django app

Tags: python, django, dropbox

I am building a web application in django where user  can download many files.

Now i have seen that files can grow in future and i can't store allt hose files in server itself . The cost will be very high.

1. Current i have files in `/storage/` which contains all files and subfolders.
2. Then in run my idexing service which basically gets the metadata like folder name , size ,  etc to put in databse so that i can make links on frontend to track stats of the dowbload file
3. This works fine but i want to know that

> 3.1 Is it possible that instead of `/storage` i store files in my `dropbox`
>
> 3.2 Then run indexing from files in dropbox
>
> 3.3 Serve the files to user from dropbox after clicking download

I think i can get the list of files via API but i am not sure how can serve the file to user which resides in dropbox

This is download only app so basically its publicly available . use does not need to upload anything. Basically i will be uploading all files in dropbox and indexing service will run daily to `update/insert/delete` files in DB tables

Comment: Dropbox is not supposed to be used as a storage service for a server. So you should'nt use it for that purpose. You could look at Amazon S3 which is basically made for this. To prove my point, I looked it up and even Dropbox use S3 to store you files.

Comment: @LaurentJalbertSimard  actually i tried s3 before but only issue is there is too much cost involved if user start downloading too may files. can google drive do something like that

Comment: At some point you will have to pay for disk space and traffic I'm afraid. You can't ask for a storage service to be both free and to allow very high traffic. Though I personally think S3 provides quite a great product for free accounts.